# Webgis with leaflet or ... with another simple solution

Tags: leaflet, geojson, web-mapping, popup

I need to create a static webgis (no connection with db!) to display my interferometric points on a map using Leaflet or similar tools. My points are in geojson but:

1. How can load these points on a map?
2. How can I wear my points with a graduated classification and colors?
3. How can I open their attribute tables with a popup?

I'm not a programmer but I'm sure that could be a tutorial or a simple way to start it with your help.